# Squarespace stretch gallery across page

Tags: html, css, squarespace

I switched over last year from cargocollective to squarespace. I'm happy with a lot of the things sqaurespace allows for. But not having access to the actual code makes customization so much more confusing for me as a novice. I tired inserting a bunch of different things into the custom CSS with no luck.

I've been playing around in the inspector element and was able **stretch the gallery across the screen** however I've had no luck actually accomplishing it through squarespace!

Any help in achieving this would be greatly appreciated! http://www.vernacularstudio.com/work/

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the shortest code necessary to reproduce it **in the question itself**.   Although you have provided a link to an example, if the link were to become invalid, your question would be of no value to other future SO users with the same problem.

Answer (score 0):

I ended up fixing it by inserting this into the custom CSS in the Design section 
The difficult part was just isolating out what the  actual div element I wanted changed was I suppose.

```
#block-yui_3_17_2_17_1431527054679_7625 .sqs-gallery-block-grid element.style {
    margin-left: 0px;
    margin-right: 0px;
    padding-left: 0px;
    padding-right: 0px;
   max-width: 100%;
}

.content-inner {
    background-color: #fff;
    max-width: 100%;
    margin: 0 auto;
    padding: 100px 8%;
   padding-left: 0px;
    padding-right: 0px;

}
```